# TypeError: f[0] is undefined in Bootstrap.min.js When this error occuured and How to fix it?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, carousel

I am making slider using bootstrap.

```
<section class="customers">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <h2> <?php echo  $FC_options['FC_customer_line'];?></h2>
            <div id="ReviewCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <?php $loop = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'Testimonials', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
                            <?php foreach ( $loop as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                        <li data-target="#ReviewCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $cur++; ?>" class="active"></li>
                        <?php  endforeach;
                               wp_reset_postdata();
                        ?>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <?php $loop = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'Testimonials', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );  ?>
                  <?php  foreach ( $loop as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                    <div class="item customer_review">
                        <p><?php echo $post->post_content;?></p>            
                        <label><?php echo $post->post_title;?></label>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach;  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                </div>
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- Container -->
</section>
```

I am getting error TypeError: f[0] is undefined.Why this error occured and how to solve it Becase my slider is not working.I have includend bootstrap.min.js. But here,main code for the slider and it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `data-ride="carousel"` from the div with `ReviewCarousel`, this sometimes cause the problem and give the *TypeError: f[0]*.

Try and check...